# CANCELLED - Sitecore User Group Conference - Europe 2021

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**THE EVENT HAS BEEN CANCELLED!**

**More info: https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/13/t/11415**

The Sitecore User Group Conference brings the Sitecore user community together and provides the perfect platform to gain knowledge and get inspired by the potential within Sitecore Experience Cloud, Experience Commerce, Content Hub and more.

**Venue:** [Budapest Congress Center](https://europe.sugcon.events/Venue) (Budapest, Jagelló út 1-3, 1123, Hungary)

**When:** June 3rd - June 4th, 2021

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Feb 25 at 11:00

Comment: Thanks @MarkCassidy! Can we start the promotion earlier to enable people to book flight/hotel and buy tickets earlier? Or we have the "one month rule" for all SUGCON events?

Comment: I created a time machine. Community Bulletin promotion began Jan 26 at 11:00

Comment: Woho! Many thanks :)

Comment: Don't thank me. I accept bribes. I will collect in Budapest *gg* ;-)

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Mar 5 '21 at 9:00

Comment: @MarkCassidy can you please remove the promotion, as it has been cancelled :( Instead of this, I created another post for Global Virtual SUGCON: https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378/global-virtual-sugcon-2021

Comment: It shows correctly now, right?

Comment: @MarkCassidy yes, thank you!