# Global Virtual SUGCON 2021

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

[image: Global Virtual SUGCON 2021 logo]

The Global Virtual Sitecore User Group conference is a free online event where the sun never sets.  It will run for 24 continuous hours featuring presentations from well-known Sitecore community thoughtleaders from around the world.

**[Twitch live stream](https://twitch.tv/sugcon)**

**[YouTube live stream](https://youtu.be/p1YeFEnvOJU)**

**[Registration is open!](https://vitrualsugcon.wufoo.com/forms/m888vu20p325xf/)**

**[Agenda is published!](https://virtual.sugcon.events/Agenda)**

**More info on: https://virtual.sugcon.events**

**When (UTC):** Saturday, June 5, 2021 00:00 AM